# array type tem tipo de elemento incompleto

Tags: c, array

Não estou conseguindo compilar o meu programa, o compilador fica acusando "array type tem tipo de elemento incompleto" na função que imprime pontos.

A função que imprime ponto:

```
 float imprimePonto(struct armazenar p[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("(%9.2f, %9.2f)\n",p[i].x,p[i].y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a struct:

```
struct armazenar
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

main:

```
#define MAX 10
    int main()
    {
        struct armazenar p[MAX];
        int n=0;

        n=func_lerN();//recebendo o numero de vetores que o usuario quer digitar.

        func_lerVetor(n);
        imprimePonto(p[MAX],n);


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: como esta sendo declarado a array no código principal?

Comment: No Visual Studio Express funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Ponha o código da struct no mesmo arquivo, acima da declaração da sua função.

Comment: não funcionou colocar o codigo da struct no no mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Compilando como? (Que Compilador, que ambiente, qual comando de compilação, etc)? Qual a estrutura (está tudo em um mesmo arquivo `.c` sem nenhum *header*?)?

Comment: tem um header e eu uso o code blocks

Comment: Possível duplicata de [como faço para acessar os valores de uma struct?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170339/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-acessar-os-valores-de-uma-struct)

Answer (score 0):

Na linha `imprimePonto(p[MAX],n);` deveria ser passado o vector em si como está na assinatura da função `float imprimePonto(struct armazenar p[], int n)`, ou seja deverias substituir `imprimePonto(p[MAX],n);` por `imprimePonto(p,n);`.

O `p[MAX]` é uma posição do vector, neste caso inválida, se queres passar o vector em si tens de indicar o vector `p` e não uma posição do mesmo.