# como faço para acessar os valores de uma struct?

Tags: c, funções, array, struct

Eu preciso imprimir os valores lidos no teclado de um vetor struct que formam uma coordenada. O problema é que quando vou passar o vetor struct da função que pega e armazena os dados para função que vai imprimi-los na tela, o que sai são coordenadas (0,0) independente do que é digitado. Ja tentei passar por referencia e por valor e não deu certo de ambos os jeitos.

Provavelmente é algum erro de passagem mesmo, mas não estou conseguindo achar em nenhum lugar a maneira correta de fazer...

```
struct armazenar
{
    float x;
    float y;
};


int func_lerCoordenada(int n)
{
    struct armazenar p[MAX];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        puts("Insira a coordenada x:");
        p[i].x=lerfloat();//lerfloat só valida enrada pra float

        puts("Insira a coordenada y:");
        p[i].y=lerfloat();

        printf("%f,%f\n",p[i].x,p[i].y);//só verificando que os valores lidos estão sendo armazenados corretamente, portanto o problema não é aqui.

    }
    return 0;
}


float imprimePonto(struct armazenar p[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("(%9.2f, %9.2f)\n",p[i].x,p[i].y);
    }
    return 0;
}


float comparacao(struct armazenar p[],int n)
{
    int i, pac=0,pab=0,pes=0,pdi=0;
    float dir=0,esq,acima=0,abaixo=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(p[i].y>acima)
        {
            acima=p[i].y;
            pac=i;//para registrar a posicao em que a condicao era verdadeira
        }
        else
        if(p[i].y<abaixo)
        {
            abaixo=p[i].y;
            pab=i;
        }

        if(p[i].x>dir)
        {
            dir=p[i].x;
            pdi=i;
        }
        else
        if(p[i].x<esq)
        {
            esq=p[i].x;
            pes=i;
        }

    }
    printf("O ponto mais acima eh: (%9.2f,%9.2f).\n\n",p[pac].x,p[pac].y);
    printf("O ponto mais abaixo eh: (%9.2f,%9.2f).\n\n",p[pab].x,p[pab].y);
    printf("O ponto mais a esquerda eh: (%9.2f,%9.2f).\n\n",p[pes].x,p[pes].y);
    printf("O ponto mais a direita eh: (%9.2f,%9.2f).\n\n",p[pdi].x,p[pdi].y);
}


int main()
{
    struct armazenar p[MAX];
    int n=0;

    n=func_lerN();//recebendo o numero de vetores que o usuario quer digitar.

    func_lerCoordenada(n);
    imprimePonto(&p[MAX],n);
    comparacao(&p[MAX],n);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema está no `main`, quando você declara seu vetor `struct armazenar p[MAX]` é criado uma sequencia dos valores.

```
    0         1       2        3        4      N
__________________________________________________
|armazena|armazena|armazena|armazena|armazena|...|
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

Repare que no `main`, você cria o seu vetor, mas você não insere valores nele. Então sempre que chegar ao método `imprimePonto` mostrará **0**

A resolução é alterar o método `func_lerCoordenada` fazendo com que ele receba o seu vetor como parâmetro.

```
/* usar *p ou p[] é a mesma coisa quando usado dentro do método*/
int func_lerCoordenada(struct armazenar *p, int n){
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        puts("Insira a coordenada x:");
        p[i].x=lerfloat();//lerfloat só valida enrada pra float

        puts("Insira a coordenada y:");
        p[i].y=lerfloat();

        printf("%f,%f\n",p[i].x,p[i].y);//só verificando que os valores lidos estão sendo armazenados corretamente, portanto o problema não é aqui.

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Todo vetor em ***C/C++*** é um endereço de memória que armazena uma sequencia predefinida de valores, que diferente de um *Ponteiro* não necessita ser alocado dinamicamente e não da para alterar seu tamanho.

---

E na hora de imprimir os dados você está passando `&p[MAX]` ou seja você está passando o endereço da ultima posição+1 do vetor, desse modo não haverá informações para serem mostradas na tela.

Como o seu método percorre o vetor desde o inicio dele, deve passar apenas o vetor sem nenhuma posição.

```
int main(){
    struct armazenar p[MAX];
    int n=0;

    n=func_lerN();

    func_lerCoordenada(p, n);
    imprimePonto(p, n);
    comparacao(p, n);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz esse exemplo, da para ter uma ideia.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Ponto {

    int x;
    int y;
}ponto;

ponto* atribuir(ponto **p) {

    printf("Digite x: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*p)->x);
    printf("Digite y: ");
    scanf("%d", &(*p)->y);
    return *p;
}

void exibir(ponto *p) {
    printf("\nExibindo Pontos.\n");
    printf("ponto x: %d\n", p->x);
    printf("ponto y: %d\n", p->y);
}
int main()
{
    ponto *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(ponto));
    p = atribuir(&p);
    exibir(p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente essa resposta vai ser inutil pra mim pois não aprendi isso ainda e não entendi o que tem que ser feito, mas obrigada.

Comment: Você tem que passar a struct na função de leitura.

Comment: ou faz a da função apontar para a do parâmetro.